# Use a Class Name to display #ID+this.substring(1) (the dot)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got several ID's with the same class specifications but the text content who changes.
With jQuery, I'd like to call my class `.job` on a click function to display the appropriate `#paper_appropriatejob`.

```
<script src="src/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(".job").click(function(){
    var theclass:String = this;
    var thejob:String = theclass.substring(1);
    $("#paper_"+thejob).fadeIn(400);
});
</script>
```

I tried next one first qith but no even results:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".job").click(function(){
    $("#paper_"+ this).fadeIn(400);
});
</script>
```

The HTML :

```
<div id="inge_sys" class="job" style= "background-image: url('src/img/salles/explo/ingesys.png')"></div>
<div id="cosmo" class="job" style= "background-image: url('src/img/salles/explo/cosmo.png')"></div>
<div id="astro" class="job" style= "background-image: url('src/img/salles/explo/astro.png')"></div>


<div id="paper_cosmo" class="paper">Text</div>
<div id="paper_astro" class="paper">Text</div>
```

Comment: Can you include your HTML? Inside your click handler `this` will be the `DOMElement` clicked; you probably want to retrieve an attribute or property from the element (`this`)... e.g. `this.id`, `this.className`; see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node

Comment: Can you give an example of an element that would be clicked?

If you have something like <div id="paper_someJob" class="job"></div>

Then, your click function to fade it just needs to do:

$(this).fadeIn(400); No need to do another select, unless you need to manipulate it in some way?

Comment: `var theclass:String = this;` is not valid JavaScript syntax. Although JavaScript and ActionScript are cousins, this doesn't mean they share all of the same syntax; you don't type-declare your vars in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, this is no a valid syntax:

```
var theclass:String = this;
```

if you want to a string value of id or a class, just use this:

```
var thisClass = $(this).attr('class');
// or 
var id = $(this).attr('id');
```

then you can do what you wanted:

```
$("#paper_"+ thisClass).fadeIn(400);
```

Comment: never use `$(this).attr('id')` when you can just use `this.id`

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest:

```
$(".job").click(function(){
    $("#paper_"+ this.id).fadeIn(400);
});
```

And if you only want to have one of the `.paper` elements showing at a time:

```
$(".job").click(function(){
    $('.paper').fadeOut(function(){
        $("#paper_"+ this.id).fadeIn(400);
    });
});
```

Comment: Very clean, also +1 for the use of `this.id`

Comment: It works great too, it'll surely be useful for another situation, thanks for the help David Thomas